# The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, asp.net-4.5

When I create new `ASP.NET 4.5` web forms application from `vs2012` and update all `nuget` packages, I receive this error on build:

> Error 1   The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.MergeBindingRedirectsFromElements(IEnumerable`1 dependentAssemblies)
>          at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It's a bug in `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` and to solve it you have to put `culture` info in the `assemblyIdentity`-part of `web.config` or `app.config`.

For example if you have:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

change it to:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: there is no 

<dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>

written anywhere in web.config

Comment: System.Web.Helpers was just a example, check for dependentAssembly and add cultureinfo to all inside that element

Comment: Thanks! This helped! but what is culture="neutral"?

Comment: A neutral culture is a culture which represents general languages like English or Spanish and a specific language and region.
(http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam3168-what-is-the-meaning-of-neutral-cultures-in-aspnet.aspx)

Answer (score 18):

I had this error but slightly different, took me 45 minutes to figure it out so thought I'd better get this out there.

Was experiencing the `"EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly` problem but mine came from an XmlException:

> (...)\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018: System.Xml.XmlException: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 39, position 175.

Turns out the cause was that I'd recently added an entry to my web.config's `appSettings` where the `value` was a URL that contained an ampersand (&).

Ampersands need to be escaped in XML, even in attribute values.

I changed all the `&` in the URL value to `&amp;` and it built without issue.

Comment: this was my issue as well, such a cryptic error, you saved me a lot of time though, thanks!

Comment: Nice spot JHo - saved me a lot of stress

Comment: In my case I had a `<` and a `>` in a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 15):

In my case issue have revealed after I merged a branch which broke my `web.config` file. It added comment character sequence `<!--` without closing part `-->`.

Making file markup valid fixed the issue.

Comment: Thx! This was the cause here too. I would probably not have discovered it without your comment, since the error was in the Web.config file and not the *.csproj file that I thought it referred to. You learn something new every day ;)

Comment: I also had a corrupted web.config.  Once fixed, project compiled

Answer (score 10):

Update `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` to fix this.

Run this on Package Manager console:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build
```

Answer (score 4):

In general it's Microsoft.Bcl.Build failling. In my case was after a merge and Git add invalid data to my web.config. Just open the web.config file and check for lines like this:

- <<<<<<< HEAD
- =======
- >>>>>>> dev

Remove them.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of Microsoft.Bcl.Build (1.0.6) has been pushed up to NuGet.org to fix this problem.  The workaround to add the culture to the assemblyIdentity is no longer necessary but won't hurt if you leave it in.

Comment: I tried 2 days back, it still breaks. Dunno which parallel universe this new package is in! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following steps can be performed to solve the issue:

1. Update the **"Microsoft.Bcl.Build**" package to the latest version.
2. Make sure you have an *App.config/Web.config* file under your project and it also exists physically in a relevant folder on your machine.
3. Make sure there are no special characters in the *App.config/Web.config* file. If they exist you need to replace them. Look at this article -> https://support.crossref.org/hc/en-us/articles/215652783-Special-characters-in-your-XML
4. In *App.config/Web.config* file under each `<dependentAssembly>` add the following key-value pair: `culture="neutral"` to `<assemblyIdentity ... />`.
5. Another step that describes how to fix your unique case and has been not described above :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a reference of a file which actually doesn't exists in your solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had a BIN and OBJ folder marked read only. Remove the read-only on *.dll.config and *.app.config or delete those folders.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the  tag was not on the first line of the file. Fixed that and everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to an appSettings value in web.config which contained a url with a & character.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened because App.Config wasn't in the folder and there were other app.configs meant for different env. So  I copied it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but mine was caused by having xml transform directives in web.config

Error       The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Xml.XmlException: 'xdt' is an undeclared prefix. Line 27, position 59.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos)

I had copied and pasted an appsetting from one of the transforms.
The solution was to remove the transform attributes

(granted this is not the exact issue the OP had, but could help someone else)

Answer (score 0):

```
I resolved this by following these steps:
```

1.) Delete Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.13 from solution\packages.

2.) After it Closes the solution, then open the solution.

3.) Navigate to tools/Nuget package manager.

4.) Press Restore Packages in right top corner of the window, after it Re-build the solution.