# Build failed in Appharbor - The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, appharbor

I've been trying to build my first application on appharbor through bitbucket, but the build process fails with the following message.

```
Build started 12/3/2014 7:22:41 PM.
     1>Project "D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz_git.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
       The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (839,131)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
     1>Project "D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz_git.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
     2>D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018: The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly. [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Referenced assembly does not exist. [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.28\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll' [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.d__6.MoveNext() [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.Execute() [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(97,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext() [D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj]
     2>Done Building Project "D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz.App\BuzzWiz.App.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\temp\n5ivm3kq.n2s\input\BuzzWiz_git.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

I have tried many things, like updating all the dependent assemblies with the neutral culture in web.config, or including the dll files in the repository, or even changing the project file to include the Condition.Exists in the Import Project tag, but I keep getting an error.

What am I missing?

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832256/the-ensurebindingredirects-task-failed-unexpectedly)